# Python Error: NoneType object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have cut down the code to show only the sections that I believe to be relevant for the following error.  This is done in python 3.x as I am trying to teach myself, so I do not have any prior experience with python 2.x

Thanks!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "rpcombat_refactored.py", line 306, in <module> shopping = buy_equipment()
File "rpcombat_refactored.py", line 242, in buy_equipment
print("You have a", join_with_and(profile['inventory']), "in your bag.")
File "rpcombat_refactored.py", line 94, in join_with_and elif sequence < 1:
TypeError: unorderable types: list() < int()
```

Code:

```
def join_with_and(sequence):
    if len(sequence) > 1:
        last_item = sequence[-1]
        sentence = ", ".join(sequence[:-1])
        sentence = sentence + " and " + last_item
    elif sequence < 1:
        sentence = "whole lot of nothing"
    else:
        sentence = sequence[0]
    return sentence

def buy_equipment():

    # Omitting item list
    # Omitting purchase prompt

    # If the item is in stock and the player has enough gold, buy it
    if purchase in stock:
        if stock[purchase][0] <= profile['gold']:
            test_phrase = profile['Name'] + " buys themself some equipment"
            print(fix_gender(profile['Gender'],test_phrase))
            print("You buy a", purchase, "for", stock[purchase][0], "gold    pieces.")
            profile['gold'] -= stock[purchase][0]
            profile['inventory'].append(purchase)
            print("You have a", join_with_and(profile['inventory']), "in  your bag.")
            print("You have", profile['gold'], "left.")
        else:
            print("You don't have enough gold to buy that.")
    elif purchase == 'done' or purchase == "":
        return profile['inventory'] == [] and profile['gold'] > 10
    else:
        print("We don't have", purchase, "in stock.")
    return purchase
```

Comment: You need to a) reduce the code to the essentials that reproduce the error, and b) ensure that it is correctly indented. Use the `{}` button on the editor toolbar after selecting your code to indent it after pasting. Your `generate_rpc()` function returns `None` because there is no explicit `return` statement anywhere, the most likely cause of this error. However, without indentation I cannot be sure.

Comment: Evidently `profile is None`, but you'll have to cut the code down to a [mcve] if you want people to tell you why; digging through hundreds of lines of code is hardly appealing!

Answer (score 1):

Your `generate_rpc` method doesn't return the profile.  It returns nothing.  So the `profile` is None.

Comment: Thank you Brian / Martijn / jonrsharpe, you are correct, this was the issue causing the error described.  If I may ask another item, now the program is spitting out the following error when I finish shopping.  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rpcombat_refactored.py", line 307, in <module>
    handbag = join_with_and(profile['inventory'])
  File "rpcombat_refactored.py", line 94, in join_with_and
    elif sequence < 1:
TypeError: unorderable types: list() < int()

Comment: @masterj1109 `sequence` is clearly a list a `list`, and Python 3.x doesn't let you compare different types (it will work in Python 2.x, although likely still not with the behaviour you expect). Please get a [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: @jonrsharpe:  Thank you for the help!  I did have to look up the rubber duck reference but it did help.  The book (I am noticing a LOT of errors that made it past review) forgot to include the length function is the second condition for the if statement.  It should have been if "len(sequence) < 1"...